# How to bound time using Stata?

Tags: time, stata

I want to restrict `TRD_EVENT_TM` variable of my dataset, which is time value, between 9:30 t0 11:00.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str8 TRD_EVENT_TM str6 TRD_STCK_CD double TRD_PR long TRD_EVENT_DT
"09:53:17" "BANK1"   909 18293
"10:25:40" "HSHM1"  1706 19205
"11:32:03" "SIPA1"  2231 18866
"11:01:55" "AZAB1"  2283 18916
"12:19:56" "SIPA1"  2063 17683
"10:48:01" "CHML1"  6048 18672
"10:59:49" "DADE1"  3044 18847
"11:40:34" "CHML1"  6406 18798
"10:54:45" "GOLG1"  7583 18544
"11:08:01" "IKCO1"  3942 18743
"10:25:35" "ASIA1"  5248 18511
"09:41:46" "FOLD1"  4910 19406
"11:43:15" "BANK1"   829 18105
end
format %tdD_m_Y TRD_EVENT_DT
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's a string variable, the condition `inrange(TRD_EVENT, "09:30", "11:00")` should work fine. With your data,

```
. list TRD_EVENT_TM if inrange(TRD_EVENT_TM, "09:30", "11:00") , sep(0) 

     +----------+
     | TRD_EV~M |
     |----------|
  1. | 09:53:17 |
  2. | 10:25:40 |
  6. | 10:48:01 |
  7. | 10:59:49 |
  9. | 10:54:45 |
 11. | 10:25:35 |
 12. | 09:41:46 |
     +----------+
```

`help inrange()` documents that the function allows string arguments. See also https://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0026

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to use the built-in `clock()` function:

```
list TRD_EVENT_TM if clock(TRD_EVENT_TM, "hms") >= clock("9:30", "hm") & ///
clock(TRD_EVENT_TM, "hms") <= clock("11:00", "hm")

    +----------+
    | TRD_EV~M |
    |----------|
 1. | 09:53:17 |
 2. | 10:25:40 |
 6. | 10:48:01 |
 7. | 10:59:49 |
 9. | 10:54:45 |
    |----------|
11. | 10:25:35 |
12. | 09:41:46 |
    +----------+
```

So if you want to restrict the variable, you can simply create a new one containing the relevant observations:

```
generate NEW_TRD_EVENT_TM = TRD_EVENT_TM if ///
clock(TRD_EVENT_TM, "hms") >= clock("9:30", "hm") & ///
clock(TRD_EVENT_TM, "hms") <= clock("11:00", "hm")
```

Comment: Last example is cleaner with `inrange()`.

Comment: What I mean is `inrange(clock(TRD_EVENT_TM, "hms"), clock("9:30", "hm"), clock("11:00", "hm"))`.